# PrimeFaces 10: sortBy not working in p:dataTable

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I migrated from PrimeFaces 6.1 to 10.0.0 and now `sortBy` of every `p:dataTable` I have in my project doesn't work.

An example of my `p:dataTable`:

```html
<p:dataTable widgetVar="truckListTable" id="truckListTable" var="truck" value="#{truckList.trucks}"
    sortBy="#{truck.code}" sortMode="single" filteredValue="#{truckList.filteredTrucks}" paginator="true"
    paginatorPosition="top" rows="20" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">
    ...
    <p:column sortBy="#{truck.plate}" filterBy="#{truck.plate}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{truck.plate}" />
    </p:column>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

I defined `truck` variable as follow in my bean `truckList`:

```java
private List<Map> trucks;

public List<Map> getTrucks() {
    return trucks;
}

public void setTrucks(List<Map> trucks) {
    this.trucks = trucks;
}
```

My problem is when I click the column header, the table rows are not sorted.

`filterBy` works fine, but `sortBy` no. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Documentation states that `sortBy` expects a single or a collection of `SortMeta`. This is also mentioned in the [from 8 to 10 migration guide](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/10_0_0?id=datatable).

So, either provide a `SortMeta` from your bean or simply add `sortOrder` to the `p:column` of the "code".

`SortMeta` can be created like:

```java
SortMeta.builder().field("code").order(SortOrder.ASCENDING).build();
```

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/datatable?id=sorting
- https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6987 – DataTable/TreeTable: sortBy not working with client saving state method

Comment: I tried to define a SortMeta and call it in sortBy of p:datatable as you said but it still not working

Comment: Did you also take a look at the linked issue?

Comment: I finally decided to stick with version 8.0

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, which cost me several hours.

Stumbled across this thread: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7232#issuecomment-822529549

Changing `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to `server` fixed the issue.

Try adding/replacing in your `web.xml`

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Comment: Thats just a hack, try using 11.0.0-RC1